# Pyomo inialization error: ERROR: evaluating expression: No value for uninitialized NumericValue object

Tags: python, optimization, pyomo

I am running a model in pyomo which is compligning of an error:

The model construction is:

```
from __future__ import division
from pyomo.environ import *
from sys import *

model = AbstractModel()


# Sets

model.Vo = Set()                           # 
model.Vf = Set()                           # 
model.Vc = Set()                           # 
model.Vfc = model.Vf | model.Vc            # 
model.V = model.Vo | model.Vf | model.Vc   # set of nodes
```

I want to create a boolean variable here with

```
# Variables

model.x_ijl = Var(model.V, model.V, model.K, within=Boolean)      # x_ijl= 1 iff l in K uses arc (i,j) in A #
```

the .dat file is:

```
set Vo := 0;
set Vf := 1 2;
set Vc := 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19;
```

But it complains of an error for both the objective and contraints in which x_ijl is used:

error in the obective:

```
ERROR: evaluating object as numeric value: ...
```

error in the constriants:

```
ERROR: evaluating expression: No value for uninitialized NumericValue object
```

Initializing x_ijl to zero or one, doesn't make sense to me since it is a boolean variable.

Could someone help me figure the best way?

EDIT: this is the Traceback:

```
Objectives:
    obj : Size=1, Index=None, Active=True
ERROR: evaluating expression: No value for uninitialized NumericValue object
x_ijl[0,5,1]
    (expression: 67*x_ijl[0,5,1] + 67*x_ijl[0,5,2] + 67*x_ijl[0,5,3] +
    67*x_ijl[0,5,4] + 70*x_ijl[0,6,1] + 70*x_ijl[0,6,2] + 70*x_ijl[0,6,3]
    + 70*x_ijl[0,6,4] + 70*x_ijl[0,7,1] + 70*x_ijl[0,7,2] +
    70*x_ijl[0,7,3] + 70*x_ijl[0,7,4] + 81*x_ijl[0,10,1] +
    81*x_ijl[0,10,2] + 81*x_ijl[0,10,3] + 81*x_ijl[0,10,4] +
    73*x_ijl[1,5,1] + 73*x_ijl[1,5,2] + 73*x_ijl[1,5,3] + 73*x_ijl[1,5,4]
    + 63*x_ijl[1,6,1] + 63*x_ijl[1,6,2] + 63*x_ijl[1,6,3] +
    63*x_ijl[1,6,4] + 69*x_ijl[1,7,1] + 69*x_ijl[1,7,2] + 69*x_ijl[1,7,3]
    + 69*x_ijl[1,7,4] + 75*x_ijl[1,10,1] + 75*x_ijl[1,10,2] +
    75*x_ijl[1,10,3] + 75*x_ijl[1,10,4] + 95*x_ijl[1,11,1] +
    95*x_ijl[1,11,2] + 95*x_ijl[1,11,3] + 95*x_ijl[1,11,4] +
    66*x_ijl[2,6,1] + 66*x_ijl[2,6,2] + 66*x_ijl[2,6,3] + 66*x_ijl[2,6,4]
    + 80*x_ijl[2,7,1] + 80*x_ijl[2,7,2] + 80*x_ijl[2,7,3] +
    80*x_ijl[2,7,4] + 73*x_ijl[2,8,1] + 73*x_ijl[2,8,2] + 73*x_ijl[2,8,3]
    + 73*x_ijl[2,8,4] + 85*x_ijl[2,11,1] + 85*x_ijl[2,11,2] +

...
...

ERROR: evaluating expression: No value for uninitialized NumericValue object
x_ijl[0,8,4]
    (expression: x_ijl[0,8,4] + x_ijl[1,8,4] + x_ijl[2,8,4] + x_ijl[3,8,4]
    + x_ijl[4,8,4] + x_ijl[5,8,4] + x_ijl[6,8,4] + x_ijl[7,8,4] +
    x_ijl[8,8,4] + x_ijl[9,8,4] + x_ijl[10,8,4] + x_ijl[11,8,4] +
    x_ijl[12,8,4] + x_ijl[13,8,4] + x_ijl[14,8,4] + x_ijl[15,8,4] +
    x_ijl[16,8,4] + x_ijl[17,8,4] + x_ijl[18,8,4] + x_ijl[19,8,4] -
    x_ijl[8,0,4] - x_ijl[8,1,4] - x_ijl[8,2,4] - x_ijl[8,3,4] -
    x_ijl[8,4,4] - x_ijl[8,5,4] - x_ijl[8,6,4] - x_ijl[8,7,4] -
    x_ijl[8,8,4] - x_ijl[8,9,4] - x_ijl[8,10,4] - x_ijl[8,11,4] -
    x_ijl[8,12,4] - x_ijl[8,13,4] - x_ijl[8,14,4] - x_ijl[8,15,4] -
    x_ijl[8,16,4] - x_ijl[8,17,4] - x_ijl[8,18,4] - x_ijl[8,19,4])
    Key : Lower : Body : Upper

...
...

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 17, in <module>
instance.display()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyomo/core/base/block.py", line 1890, in display
Block.display(self, filename, ostream, prefix)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyomo/core/base/block.py", line 1870, in display
_BlockData.display(self[key], filename, ostream, prefix)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyomo/core/base/block.py", line 1621, in display
obj.display(prefix=prefix + "    ", ostream=ostream)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyomo/core/base/constraint.py", line 843, in display
lambda k, v: [ value(v.lower),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyomo/core/base/misc.py", line 245, in tabular_writer
+ "\n")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyomo/core/base/misc.py", line 244, in <genexpr>
+ " : ".join( _width[i] % x for i,x in enumerate(_data) )
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Comment: Binary variables such as `model.x_ijl` cannot be directly used in python `if` statements. I suspect that's where the error occurs. A stack trace would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks @Oi, I have added the trace.

Comment: The traceback refers to a different error than your question asks?

Comment: I just sent part of the error because of its lenght, the error started from the once I  posted earlier before the trace, i felt i should start with the origin of the error! I have edited! you can have a look again. thankx

Comment: For the time being, try using `model.pprint()` instead of `model.display()` for troubleshooting before you call the `solve()` statement. I have raised the `display()` issue on Github. https://github.com/Pyomo/pyomo/issues/616

Comment: Oh kk! never knew the fault could be from `.display()`. Thanks @Qi, your comments have being very helpful.